# Cowardly refuses to write to a non-existent directory - JAXB

Tags: java, xml, linux, xsd, jaxb

I'm getting the following error when trying to generate Java classes from an XSD schema using JAXB. I'm specifying a directory that I want them to be in but I am getting the following error when I try to run the command.

Command:

`java -jar /home/Alison/Programs/jaxb-ri-2.2.6/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar xmlSchema.xjb -d com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.model.xmlclasses xmlSchema.xsd`

Error:

> cowardly refuses to write to a non-existent directory "com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.model.xmlclasses"

I found the following patch http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAXB-2 but from the comments it seems that it no longer works with the current revision.

Is there any way I can specify to create the directory if it does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manged to get this to work the way I wanted using the following command:

`java -jar /home/Alison/Programs/jaxb-ri-2.2.6/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar -b xmlSchema.xjb -d src -p com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.model.xmlclasses xmlSchema.xsd`

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way I can specify to create the directory if it does not exist?

The simple answer is to create the directory *before* you run the application.  In general, there is no way to get an application to create a directory for you if the application doesn't already have the capability to create directories.

FWIW, it is generally a bad idea for an application to create "missing" directories ... unless the user has indicated that that is what is required; e.g. via a command line option.  The reason is that "missing" directories are *usually* due to the user mistyping a pathname, or due to the current directory being different to what the user thinks it is.  In other words, the user *usually* wouldn't want the application to create the "missing" directories.

Comment: So is there no way to do this? The Windows command line has this functionality and as there was a patch released so there must be a way. I was looking to have it created as part of an ANT task when building the project.

Comment: If the Windows shell will automatically a directory if you enter a pathname with an incorrect directory part, that is a BUG ... IMO.  Certainly no UNIX / Linux shell does anything that stupid.

Comment: The purpose of the patch was to modify the application to add a capability that wasn't there. There's no reason you couldn't implement what the patch was doing by modifying the latest version of the application. But the point is that you can't get an unmodified application to create directories if it doesn't already have that capability.  Now, as it turns out, the real problem was (apparently) just that you had gotten the command arguments wrong ... and there's a lesson there too.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this issue when I try to generate java package and files at runtime.
Issue occurs when I already have a specified java package which is created at runtime and again I am trying to create the same jaxb classes(first time when it got created,there were some functional errors and after that files didnt get deleted) it says
"cowardly refuses to write to a non-existent directory "employee"".
For me the issue got **solved** when i manually deleted the already created package ,after that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the issue but solved it using following way.

`xjc -d src/main/java -p com.sample.utils.jaxbJavaClass /Users/XXXX/Documents/Project_workspace/src/test/resources/xsd_files/out.xsd`

In the above command `-d` represents source directory, `-p` the package where you want the java classes to be generated. Then use your project director path and your "xsd" file path. This above command works fine and java classes will be generated.